# asp.net VB Concatenating String in SQL Query

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a ASP.NET VB app that attempts to connect to a SQL database through a SQL Query. I have it currently set up so that the user enters a name of a member in a textBox through the following:

```
<SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="textEntry" Name="Member_Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

I then have a GridView with a SQLDataSource. Inside the SelectCommand, I have the following string that tries to reference Member_Name from the textbox:

```
 SelectCommand = "SELECT [Membership_ID], [Membership_Name], Sum([Spend_Total]) as Spend_Total FROM [Member_Table]
            WHERE ([Membership_Name] LIKE" '%' +  @Member_Name + '%' +") 
            GROUP BY Membership_ID, Membership_Name
            "
```

But this does not work. I essentially am trying to replicate the SQL  LIKE '% string %' functionality, but I can't see what is wrong with my code/how to fix it.

Comment: why the `"` and `&"`? try `SELECT [Membership_ID], [Membership_Name], Sum([Spend_Total]) as Spend_Total FROM [Member_Table]
            WHERE [Membership_Name] LIKE '%' +  @Member_Name + '%' 
            GROUP BY Membership_ID, Membership_Name`

Comment: I suggest that you first try it with an `=` instead of a `LIKE` and remove the "%"s, then use an actual entry from the database. It is one less thing to debug.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this is what I ended up doing! Too many complications with LIKE, and also longer querying times too!

Answer (score -1):

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT [Membership_ID], [Membership_Name], Sum([Spend_Total]) as Spend_Total FROM [Member_Table]
        WHERE ([Membership_Name] LIKE '%' +  @Member_Name + '%') 
        GROUP BY Membership_ID, Membership_Name
        "
```

Comment: Hello. This did not work for me. I'm having the same issues as before.

Comment: "same issue" doesn't help us any, since the original question never shares the error reported by the server.

Comment: As a side-question, can one use the concatentation operator "+" within a string? I thought they could only be used outside of strings.

Comment: Just asking the question in the above comment, because you’ve placed the concatenation operator within a string.

Comment: @ThomasMoore The + sign is part of the SQL. It's not concatenating two strings in .Net